# How do I schedule a one-time script to run x minutes from now? (alternative for 'at')

Tags: python, bash, shell, scheduled-tasks, raspberry-pi

(Background: I'd like to control a light source with a motion sensor. Light should turn off x minutes after last detected motion. The framework is in place, scheduling is what remains to be done.)

Currently, when motion is detected the light gets turned on and a job to turn it off in 'now + x minutes' is scheduled. Whenever motion is detected during the x minutes the job gets removed from the queue and a new one is set up, extending effectively the time the light stays on.

I tried the "at" command but job handling is quite clunky. Whenever a job is removed from the queue an email gets sent. I looked at the Python crontab module but it would need much additional programming (handling relative time, removing old cronjobs, etc.) and seems to be slower.

What are my alternatives (bash, python, perl)?

-- Edit: My python skills are at beginner level, here's what I put together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# based on http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio-part-2
# more than 160 seconds without activity are required to re-trigger action

import time
from subprocess import call
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

PIR = 9 # data pin of PIR sensor (in)
LED = 7 # positive pin of LED (out)
timestamp = '/home/pi/events/motiontime' # file to store last motion detection time (in epoch)
SOUND = '/home/pi/events/sounds/Hello.wav' # reaction sound

# GPIO setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(PIR,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(LED,GPIO.OUT)

# function which gets called when motion is reported (sensor includes own delay-until-hot again
# and sensibility settings
def my_callback(channel):
        now = time.time() # store current epoch time in variable 'now'
        f = open(timestamp, "r") 
        then = float(f.readline()) # read last detection time from file
        difference = now - then # calculate time that has passed
    call(['/home/pi/bin/kitchenlights.sh', '-1']) # turn light on
    call(['/home/pi/bin/lighttimer.sh']) # schedule at job to turn lights off
    if difference > 160: # if more than 160 seconds without activity have passed then...
                GPIO.output(LED, True) # turn on LED
                if not os.path.isfile("/home/pi/events/muted"): # check if system is muted, else
                        call(['/usr/bin/mplayer', '-really-quiet', '-noconsolecontrols', SOUND]) # play sound
                GPIO.output(LED, False) # turn of LED
                f = open(timestamp, "w") 
                f.write(repr(now)) # update timestamp
                f.close()
        else: # when less than 160 seconds have passed do nothing and
                f = open(timestamp, "w")
                f.write(repr(now)) # update timestamp (thus increasing the interval of silence)
                f.close()

GPIO.add_event_detect(PIR, GPIO.RISING,callback=my_callback,bouncetime=100)  # add rising edge detection on a channel

while True:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        pass
```

Now that questions come in I think I could put a countdown in the while loop, right? How would that work?

Comment: If you did it in Python, would the script run continuously, or only after motion is detected?

Comment: If you've already got a process monitoring for motion, I'd have the turn-off action as part of the same process rather than queueing a separate process to turn it off.

Comment: Just making sure I understand this, ```my_callback()``` runs every time motion is detected by your sensor?

Comment: @wnnmaw yes. So I guess my_callback() should also be able extend/restart the countdown. And since it runs constantly in the background I need to keep it resource-freiendly.

Comment: Make your callback just set the last updated time, and in your 'while True' loop check whether `current - last_update > 160` and if so run the script in the background.

Comment: Whats the difference between your light and LED?

Comment: @wnnmaw LED is a local LED for control. The actual (remote controlled) light is turned on or off via the bash script /home/pi/bin/kitchenlights.sh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this with the `threading` module.  To do this, you'd set up the following thread class:

```
class CounterThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.count = 0
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while self.count < COUNTLIMIT:
            time.sleep(0.1)            
            self.count += 0.1

        #Call function to turn off light here                
        return

    def newSig(self):
        self.count = 0
```

This is a thread which everytime it recieves a new signal (the thread's `newSig` function is called), the counter restarts.  If the `COUNTLIMIT` is reached (how long you want to wait in seconds), then you call the function to turn off the light.

Here's how you'd incorporate this into your code:

```
import threading
from subprocess import call
import os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

PIR = 9 # data pin of PIR sensor (in)
LED = 7 # positive pin of LED (out)
SOUND = '/home/pi/events/sounds/Hello.wav' # reaction sound

COUNTLIMIT = 160
countThread = None
WATCHTIME = 600 #Run for 10 minutes

# GPIO setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(PIR,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(LED,GPIO.OUT)

#------------------------------------------------------------

class CounterThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.count = 0
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        call(['/home/pi/bin/kitchenlights.sh', '-1'])     # turn light on
        while self.count < COUNTLIMIT:
            time.sleep(0.1)            
            self.count += 0.1

        call(['/home/pi/bin/kitchenlights.sh', '-0']) 
        threadKiller()
        return

    def newSig(self):
        self.count = 0

#------------------------------------------------------------

def my_callback(channel):
    '''function which gets called when motion is reported (sensor includes own delay-until-hot again and sensibility settings'''

    global countThread

    try: 
        countThread.newSig()
    except:
        countThread = CounterThread() 

#------------------------------------------------------------

def threadKiller():
    global countThread
    countThread = None

#------------------------------------------------------------

def main():
    GPIO.add_event_detect(PIR, GPIO.RISING,callback=my_callback,bouncetime=100)  # add rising edge detection on a channel
    t = 0
    while t < WATCHTIME:
        t += 0.1
        time.sleep(0.1)

#------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

I don't have any way to test this, so please let me know if there is anything that breaks. Since you said you're new to Python I made a few formatting changes to make your code a bit prettier.  These things are generally considered to be good form, but are optional. However, you need to be careful about indents, because as you have them in your question, your code should not run (it will throw an `IndentError`)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this looks great, I will incorporate it. It may take a day, though, until I am able to report back.

Comment: I added the command that turns lights off. It seems that the code is not whileing or looping. The script runs and finishes without any effect.

Comment: @PiEnthusiast, I've added some print statements, let me know what these get you

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your tenacity and see this as a good learning opportunity for me.  

Yet, regrettably, nothing happens, nothing is printed. The original script had an idle while loop which, if I interpret it correctly, got interrupted by the callback. Does your "if __name__ == "__main__": main()" serve the same purpose?

Comment: @PiEnthusiast No, the ```if __name__ == "__main__": main()``` line runs the ```main()``` function ([here is a good explanation of how it works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)).  I think I know what hte problem is.  Once the line in ```main()``` runs, the script finishes and exits, which is why you had the ```while``` loop (which I stupidly omitted).  I added it back in now

Comment: OK, this is much better now. I had to import the time module and to not have to wait too long I lowered the countdown values. Regrettably, it looks like it is possible that several threads run in parallel while actually any new activity should kill any previous thread. This adds up and I get quite a light show. :)

Comment: @PiEnthusiast, I assmue you figured this out because it prints ```creating new thread``` a bunch of times.  Try adding ```print sys.exc_info()[1]``` right by that line (and ```import sys``` up top)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46282/discussion-between-pienthusiast-and-wnnmaw)